# What can cause the react application to load indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was writing a project for a college and at some point my react application suddenly started displaying this picture:[infinity loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYLOU.png).

I have tried commenting on the lines I added last, but have not been able to solve the problem.

Here's the code: https://github.com/chiester86/fumo-market.git

Comment: Please add your code snippet relevant to the question

Comment: The problem is that I don't know exactly where the error is, so I can't post a snippet of code here

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/ You can use this platform to upload your env and share it

Comment: Maybe I'll upload the project to GitHub and share it?

Comment: That works as well

Comment: I added a link to the question

Comment: So are you trying to run the front end only at the moment? And you'd better create a `.gitignore` file in your root directory and add `.env` file and `/node_modules` directory

Comment: The problem is with the frontend, because I haven't updated the backend. OK, I'll try to add what you said, but this is my first time working with GitHub, so it might take a bit longer

Comment: It's not mandatory, but it's the general recommendation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.